# Nested generator object context

Tags: python, generator

today I've played around with nested generator functions and found an interesting property / behavior which I can't explain to myself.

Maybe this is associated with a lack of understanding of what `yield from` does…. However, now to the problem:

```
def foo():
    for iter in range(10):
        yield iter

generator = foo()

def bar():
    yield from generator

print(next(bar()), end=' ')
print(next(bar()), end=' ')
...
```

So the output I excepted would be `0 1 ...`.

However, after the first successfull call to `next`, I get:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    StopIteration

So my question is: Why has the generator already reached its end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `generator` object is a global; you never create a new one. Once iterated over **or closed**, it is exhausted.

It is closed because you used `yield from` in a function. When the `bar` generator function ends, the `GeneratorExit` exception is propagated to the underlying generator (so the `foo()` instance), and it is closed too. `bar()` ends, because there are no references to the object and it is cleaned up.

From the [*Yield expressions* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions):

> When `yield from <expr>`is used, it treats the supplied expression as a subiterator. All values produced by that subiterator are passed directly to the caller of the current generator’s methods. Any values passed in with `send()` and any exceptions passed in with `throw()` are passed to the underlying iterator if it has the appropriate methods.

and from [PEP-380 *Syntax for Delegating to a Subgenerator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/):

> If a `GeneratorExit` exception is thrown into the delegating generator, or the `close()` method of the delegating generator is called, then the `close()` method of the iterator is called if it has one.

In detail, what happens, is this:

- `generator = foo()` creates a new generator object.
- `bar()` creates another. There are no references to this object however, other than the stack.
- `next()` takes the `bar()` generator from the stack and forwards it one step.
- `next()` returns, and there are no references left to the `bar()` generator, so it is deleted.
- Deleting a generator object calls the [`generator.close()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.close), raising `GeneratorExit` in the generator, via [`generator.throw()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.throw).
- `yield from` propagates that exception to the `foo()` generator object by closing that too.